# Group in which all elements are conjugate

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Two elements $a$ and $b$ of a group $G$ are conjugate if there is an element $g$ in the group such that $b = g^{–1}ag$.

I was going through the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) on conjugacy classes and was curious about this:

What can we say about a group $G$ in which all its elements are conjugate? Does it have any special properties? Can there exist such a non-trivial group $G$?

Comment: To make it more interesting, consider replacing "all elements are conjugate" with "all _non-identity_ elements are conjugate". Then, the cyclic group of order $2$ would be such a group.

Comment: @saltandpepper: If the group is abelian, then every element is conjugate **only to itself**.

Comment: A group in which every element is conjugate is trivial, since $e$ can only be conjugate to itself. A group with exactly two conjugacy classes, one for the identity and one for every other element, is either cyclic of order $2$, or must be infinite, and the constructions are difficult, and the question is then a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it cannot. That's because the identity element is conjugate with itself and only with itself.

Comment: This would no longer be a valid answer after my suggestion above to replace "all elements are conjugate" with "all _non-identity_ elements are conjugate" is followed.

Answer (score 1):

That can't happen unless the group is trivial.  The class equation always consists of at least one $1$, corresponding to the class of the identity.

If we change it as @GeoffreyTrang suggests, then we get only one conjugacy class of size one, and hence the center is trivial.

Comment: As with the other answer, this would no longer be a valid answer after my suggestion above to replace "all elements are conjugate" with "all _non-identity_ elements are conjugate" is followed.

Comment: Ok @GeoffreyTrang.